# Error converting bytecode to dex - Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use the Pcap library in my app. I'm getting an error in my build.gradle file when I try to compile my dependency:

```
compile 'io.pkts:pkts-core:2.0.3'
```

My build.gradle file now looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.packet_sniffer_v2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

    compile 'io.pkts:pkts-core:2.0.3'
}
```

Everything else is set to the default 'Hello World' settings when you create a new project. Error:

```
Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause:java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

It seems like this is a newer issue effecting people running AS 2.0, but I haven't found any solutions online yet.

Comment: I don't have such issue. Do I need to use class from this library to reproduce it?

Comment: No. I'm having this issue on my mac as well as my Ubuntu VM.